# Is it possible to run a Tampermonkey script with a key combo or from a context menu?

Tags: javascript, key, combinations, tampermonkey

I am unable to find out how can I assign a key combination to a Tampermonkey script. Or run the script from a context menu on the page, or from a bookmarklet, etc. I don't want to run the script every time on the specific domain, when a page loads.

Comment: See [@run-at context-menu](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php?ext=dhdg#_run_at)

Comment: Thanks, finally it works.